# 400 (Bad Request) from FastAPI

Tags: javascript, python, axios, fastapi

my pydantic model in FastAPI application

```
class FromPerson(BaseModel):
  id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
  donor_name: str
  registration: Optional[str] = None
  phone: Optional[int] = None
  amount: float
  type: str
  date: str

  class Config:
    allow_population_by_field_name = True
    arbitrary_types_allowed = True
    json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
```

values that I'm passing through axios in React

```
Axios.post("<apiUrl>", {
  donor_name: "x",
  registration: "123",
  phone: 123,
  amount: 123,
  type: "y",
  date: new Date(),
}, {
     headers: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
     }
})
```

In OpenAPI auto-generated docs, it works as expected for the protected url. But in frontend, been facing error though I'm getting and storing the token in localStorage after logged-in in client side.
And, here also the id field is optional for pydantic model. MongoDB automatically generates the id.

Comment: The body of the error should contain more information about why the request is returned as a 400 - the server log should as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. It's not showing Unauthorized error at least because the server is receiving the token, it's fine. Maybe the values I'm passing from client side have issues but how,why?

Comment: The response should include information about why the error occurs. It could be a problem with the date format, but without the error it is difficult to say

Comment: As others have mentioned already, please post the message you are getting in your terminal when the `400` occurs.

Comment: I finally then had solved the problem by myself. Thanks for your willingness to help.